# Openshift pre_start and post_start hook infinite loop

Tags: openshift, openshift-cartridge

## Hi!

I've too hooks, one for pre_start and one for post_start.

- **pre_start** start a self written script like: `nohup python foo.py > /dev/null &`
- Where **foo.py** runs continously doing stuff as usual.
- **post_start** is just for diagnosing that everything runs fine, it just calls `ps aux` and sends an e-mail about it. (It's a Python script with a shebang)

Now. As I commit and push something the rebuild starts and it ends up with an infinite loop between the two pre_start and post_start scripts :(

Just some little messages are between them, which I do not understand:

```
remote: Script /var/lib/openshift/5...3/python//virtenv/bin/activate.fish cannot be made relative (it's not a normal script that starts with #!/var/lib/openshift/5...3/python/virtenv/bin/python)
remote: Script /var/lib/openshift/5...3/python//virtenv/bin/activate.csh cannot be made relative (it's not a normal script that starts with #!/var/lib/openshift/5...3/python/virtenv/bin/python)
```

*Thanks for any help! :)*

Answer (score 0):

As I see, it's normal. As many cartridges you have so many times will your hooks be called. In my fall 4 times... I had to handle this, with renaming my hooks with a postfix `python-2.7` so: `pre_start_python-2.7`. This way it yould be run only once.

Here is the event log of the deploy process:

```
remote: Preparing build for deployment
remote: Deployment id is 4e9628aa
remote: Activating deployment
remote: pre_start called
remote: Starting Cron cartridge
remote: post_start called
remote: pre_start called
remote: Starting MongoDB cartridge
remote: Waiting for mongo to start...
remote: post_start called
remote: pre_start called
remote: Starting RockMongo cartridge
remote: post_start called
remote: Script /var/lib/openshift/5...3/python//virtenv/bin/activate.fish cannot be made relative (it's not a normal script that starts with #!/var/lib/openshift/5...3/python/virtenv/bin/python)
remote: Script /var/lib/openshift/5...3/python//virtenv/bin/activate.csh cannot be made relative (it's not a normal script that starts with #!/var/lib/openshift/5...3/python/virtenv/bin/python)
remote: pre_start called
remote: Starting Python 2.7 cartridge (Apache+mod_wsgi)
remote: Application directory "/" selected as DocumentRoot
remote: Application "wsgi.py" selected as default WSGI entry point
remote: post_start called
remote: -------------------------
remote: Git Post-Receive Result: success
```